How to create query in azure to find change in remaining work field
I want to create a query wherein we can track in a specific sprint, within 24 hour span, how many hours are burned by the team members.
My way of developing this query is if I can find change in the remaining work field , I can track it.
I have created query using @StartOfDay variable. But it is giving me data of tasks which are older than 24 hours also.
Is there any way in which I can limit it to last one day or 24 hours?


As stated in my answer below, there is no any available query macros and alternative on the On the web UI of query page to let the query can accurate to the hour time. You can consider using the Azure DevOps REST API to query the work items by hour time of the changed date. @Jay

Your clauses in the query is not accurate actually. The Changed Date monitors on any changes on the work item but not only Remaining work field.
In addition, the two Remaining work clauses with >=[Field] or <=[Field] evaluates all, which is not needed.
To find change in the Remaining work field, you can add a custom field ChangedTime for task:

add a work item rule(for inherited process), record the time when Remaining Work field is changed.

In the work item query, filter the ChangedTime which is > @StartOfDay('-1d'):

And add ChangedTime and Remaining Work in column option so it will display in the query result. You can sort the ChangedTime by time, to get the work items in 24 hours.

Or you can export the result in CSV format, and check tasks in excel instead. It supports accurate time filter:


The query macros '@StartOfDay' can only be accurate to the date, not the hour time. The expression '@StartOfDay', '@StartOfDay-1' or '@StartOfDay('-1d')' will contain the whole previous day of current date.
There is no available query macros that can be accurate to the hour time.
If your projects really need this feature, I recommend you try to report a feature request on Developer Community. This will make it more convenient for the Azure DevOps engineer teams to receive and understand your ideas. And your feedback also could be helpful for improving the Azure DevOps products.

thank you for your response. But in the meanwhile is there any alternative to achieve this?

@Jay, On the web UI of query page, there is no any alternative. Another way you can consider is calling the REST API "Work Items - List" in a script. From the response of the API, you can see the value of changed date for each item (e.g., "System.ChangedDate": "2014-06-11T20:49:20.77Z"). Then based on the changed date to further filter the items changed within 24 hours.
